# Is there an accepted terminology/notation for the vector $\langle \theta \rangle := \begin{bmatrix} \sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: geometry, notation, vectors, terminology, plane-geometry

Suppose you start off at a point $A$, walk 10 units at a bearing of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, then walk 25 more at a bearing of $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. The point where you end up is, of course,

$$A+10\left\langle \frac{\pi}{4}\right\rangle+25\left\langle \frac{5\pi}{4}\right\rangle,$$

where $$\langle \theta \rangle := \begin{bmatrix}
\sin \theta  \\
\cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix}$$

For pedagogical reasons, it would be nice to have standard notation and/or terminology for what I'm denoting here as $\langle \theta \rangle$.

> **Question.** Are there any standards here?

Comment: When dealing with Polar coordinates (especially in the context of vector calculus), that unit vector is often referred to as $\hat r$, which is implicitly understood to be a function of $\theta$.

Comment: In the Complex Plane, your vector corresponds to $\cos\theta  + i\sin\theta$, which is often abbreviated $\operatorname{cis}\theta$. (Of course, it's also written $\exp(i\theta)$.) In some of my answers here, I've (ab)used the notation $\operatorname{cis}\theta$ to refer to the vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (I make sure I explain this usage, to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is

$$\mathrm{e}^{\theta \mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y}} \cdot \mathbf{x}$$

where $\mathbf{x}$ is the basis vector for the $x$ direction, $\mathbf{y}$ is the basis vector for the $y$ direction, $\wedge$ is the wedge product, $\mathrm{e}$ is the matrix exponential, and $\cdot$ is the inner product. The rotation matrix $\mathrm{e}^{\theta \mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y}}$ is also typically denoted by $R(\theta)$.